# arrayindexoutofbounds exception processing

Tags: java, arrays, processing

i've been learning java for 2 months and i'm trying to code a game based on the creation of many proyectiles that appears in the middle of the screen every 3 seconds.
I was wondering if someone could check whats happening to my code because i really don´t know what to do, and i cant find the resolution of my problem in the other similar questions.

[edit 1]: i updated the exit of the loop.

```
int  num_proyect_act = 0;

float [] proyectil = new float [3];

float [] posX = new float [num_proyect_act];

float [] posY = new float [num_proyect_act];

float [] vX = new float [num_proyect_act];

float [] vY = new float [num_proyect_act];

int [] radix = new int [num_proyect_act];

int tiempo;

int intervalo = 3;

void setup () {
    tiempo = millis()/1000;
}

void draw () {
    if (((millis()-tiempo)/1000) > intervalo) {
        posX[num_proyect_act] = width/2;
        posY[num_proyect_act] = height/2;
        vY[num_proyect_act] = mouseY-height/2;
        vX[num_proyect_act] = mouseX-width/2;
        radix[num_proyect_act] =int(random(10, 60));
        num_proyect_act++;
      }
      println (millis()/1000);

      //meter aqui el calculo del tipo de proyectil

      for (int i= 0; i> num_proyect_act; i++) {

        dibujar_proyectil(i);
        comprovar_lim(i);
        modificar_pos(i);
      }
 }
```

void dibujar_proyectil(int _i) {

```
float r= random (10, 40);
ellipse(posX[_i], posY[_i], r, r);
```

}

Comment: provide exception for faster solution

Comment: Please post the stack trace and figure out which line the error is coming from.

Comment: You create multiple empty arrays and then try to access them. Hence your out of bounds exception

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the exit condition of your for loop:

```
for (int i= 0; i> num_proyect_act; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: void dibujar_proyectil(int _i) {

float r= random (10, 40);
ellipse(posX[_i], posY[_i], r, r);
}

Comment: i cant vote :S it wasnt me

Answer (score 0):

You're probably creating arrays with 0 length.

```
int  num_proyect_act = 0;
int [] radix = new int [num_proyect_act];
```

This also seems suspect.

```
for (int i= 0; i> num_proyect_act; i++) {
```

You probably meant:

```
for (int i= 0; i < num_proyect_act; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is likely a problem:

```
  for (int i= 0; i> num_proyect_act; i++) {

    dibujar_proyectil(i);
    comprovar_lim(i);
    modificar_pos(i);
  }
```

This will not excecute unless num_proyect_act is less than zero.  If it does execute it will run forever or until you exit it or an exception is thrown, because if I is greater than num_provect_act and you increase it by one every loop, it will always be greater than num_provect_act (until you get an overflow at least)

But your array out of bounds exception is likely coming from here:

```
    posX[num_proyect_act] = width/2;
    posY[num_proyect_act] = height/2;
    vY[num_proyect_act] = mouseY-height/2;
    vX[num_proyect_act] = mouseX-width/2;
    radix[num_proyect_act] =int(random(10, 60));
```

You have created these arrays as size num_proyect_act.  Array indexing in Java starts at 0 and goes to size-1.  So these are all out of bounds of the array.

Comment: ok, i understand the problem but i really dont know what to do, i mean how can i fix this, is this a code syntax error?

Comment: You arrays are the source of the exception. The arrays are created with length 0. So whenever you try then to access anything from your arrays you get an exception. Change the size of the arrays to avoid that.

Comment: ok, i change num_proyect_act = 200; but i still get that expection, thanks for your patience...

Comment: Further down you are accessing it again with num_proyect_act. But if you have an array of length num_proyect_act, then the last element is at position [num_proyect_act-1] and not [num_proyect_act]. You have to change that

Comment: and what should i do then?

Comment: you could change it to [num_proyect_act-1]

Comment: okey, but now the error is in the exit void dibujar_proyectil(_i) {     ellipse(posX[_i]...